How do I use a literal C char constant in a comparison with Cython?
This seems rather trivial, but I couldn't find the answer myself: How do I use a literal C char constant in a comparison with Cython?
This doesn't work:
cdef fct(char c):
    return c == 'x'

sh$ cython3 -3 t.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef fct(char c):
    return c == 'x'
               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

t.pyx:2:16: Unicode literals do not support coercion to C types other than Py_UNICODE/Py_UCS4 (for characters) or Py_UNICODE* (for strings).

Notice:

I am using Cython 0.26.1.
It does compile without error with cython3 -2.
Writing c == 'x'.encode("ascii") passes compilation but generates code that uses PyObject_RichCompare instead of doing the comparison at C-level using a simple ==




It does compile without error with cython3 -2.


This has triggered the answer: I need to use a byte string, not an unicode string:
cdef fct(char c):                                                                                                                                                                                   
    return c == b'x'    

